# What's wrong with my iFrame before and after printing with CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

- I would like to know what happen with my iFrame as the
  table in the picture 1 below which has `font-size: 20px` and `the Date,
  Requester, Place From...` got the `font-size` approximately
  `12-14px`.
- Then, I've printed that page out. There was something wrong with all
  text's size in the table as the iFrame. (Please take a look on the
  `font-size` with the picture 2 below).
- After that, I've tried to add `font-size` to CarBookingCSS.txt in
  order to make a change for the iFrame as the code below but it still
  didn't work.

**CSS:**

```
iframe {
font-size: 50px !important;
}
```

or

```
#iframe_link {
font-size: 50px !important;
}
```

**Summary**: The `font-size` of the iFrame as the table before printing and after printing are totally different. Although I've had some change with the `CarBookingCSS.txt`, it still didn't work a bit.

---

**Pic 1:**
[image: 1]

**Pic 2:**
[image: 2]

---

**HTML:**

```
<input onclick="printDiv('page_printer');" type="button" value="Print" />
<table id="page_printer">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <fieldset class="box">
                <legend class="text_transportation">EMPLOYEE GATE PASS</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Date</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <div>2014</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Requester</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <div></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Place From</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <div>P1</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Place To</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <div>P3</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Purpose</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <div></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Business date - From</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <div>2014</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Business date - To</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <div>2014</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    function printDiv(divID) {
    var printContent = document.getElementById(divID);
    var windowUrl = '';
    var uniqueName = new Date();
    var windowName = 'Print' ;
    var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=-20,top=-20,width=800px,height=600px');
    printWindow.document.write("<HTML><Head><Title></Title><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/Style%20Library/CarBookingCSS.txt' media='print' />");
    printWindow.document.write("</Head><Body style='margin-left:10px;margin-top:0px;font-weight:bold'>");
    printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</Body></HTML>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();
    //Print Page
    setTimeout(function () { print_page(); }, 1000);
    function print_page() {
        printWindow.print();
    }

    //Restore orignal HTML
    setTimeout(function () { restore_page(); }, 6000);
    function restore_page() {    
        printWindow.close();
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.ms-bodyareaframe {
    padding: 8px;
    border: none;
}
.text_transportation {
    font-size: large;
    color: red;
}
.text_approveStep {
    font-size: large;
    color: red;
}
.box {
    width: 750px !important;
}
.set_width {
    width: 350px !important;
}
.set_backgr {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #0072BC !important;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    border: none !important;
    background-color: #F6F6F6 !important;
}
.set_backgr:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.readOnly {
    background-color: #F6F6F6 !important;
    color: #676767 !important;
    border: none !important;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: So when you print the page the font size is changing and you don't want it to? Is that correct? Do you have any print css that would be changing it?

Comment: @joshhunt: That's right. As you can see, I've put all the styles here already.

Comment: Do you have anything that uses @media print or <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="print">?

Comment: @joshhunt: I've got it and you can see it in my Javascript code above as `printWindow.document.write("<HTML><Head><Title></Title><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/Style%20Library/CarBookingCSS.txt' media='print' />");`

Comment: I'm still wondering why the page before and after printing are absolutely different even I do not add anything in the CSS which might affect to the iFrame.

Comment: @PMay1903, this may be browser issue as well. Try to check it in different browser and see if this is working

Comment: Do you have it set up on a page that I could look at? Also probably not relevent... but why is your css in a .txt file?

Answer (score 1):

your css may included in the html with something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" media="screen" />
```

either delete the media="screen", or add another for printing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print"/>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp

Comment: As I've printed it out yet, It got all styles and a change of iFram which I would like to see it from the `href='/Style%20Library/CarBookingCSS.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

I think the print window doesn't get the CSS classes, so it just shows whatever there is on the HTML.. however, if the style is on the HTML, i think that it will be applied. Not entirely sure though haha but i did something like this i while ago.

Comment: As I've printed it out yet, It got all styles which I would like to see it from the `href='/Style%20Library/CarBookingCSS.txt'`.